# Broadcast Receiver when app destroyed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am looking simple that Does `Broadcast Receiver` get called of your app when OS destroy your app and manually killed by any kill manager app ??

Any ideas how this works ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Broadcast Receiver get called of your app when OS destroy your app and manually killed by any kill manager app ?

No. Your process is simply terminated.

Comment: and what about if you register your receiver in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: @Williams: That does not matter. There is no broadcast that is sent to your app telling you that your process was terminated.